# How can I interleave captured wireshark traffic?

Tags: wireshark, traffic, tshark, network-traffic

Suppose that I have traffic1.pcap file that captured traffic at the 1st, 3rd, and 5th seconds. Hence, when viewed in wireshark, there were 3 lines with each line representing traffic captured at the above time.

And another file, traffic2.pcap, that showed traffic at 2nd and 4th seconds.

How can I combine the two files so that the traffic interleaves to become 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

**EDIT:**

The time I'd like to merge is the relative time, not absolute time stamp. By relative time I mean, "the time elapsed between the first packet and the current packet," as is the case with `tshark -t r`. It is not absolute time, such as 20151210133601.

It's true that I started capturing traffic2.pcap a few seconds after traffic1.pcap finished, but they both starts at the same relative time 0.

Running `mergecap traffic1.pcap traffic2.pcap -w traffic3.pcap` still appends the file, rather than merging.

Comment: Hello Curioso. This is off-topic here; take a look at what you can ask about on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

mergecap assumes that the two packet captures start at the same time. It is interlacing the two captures just not using the time relative to the start. To do that you need to change the start time of the captures to match

```sh
    editcap -t 14272376 capture1.pcap capture1-shifted.pcap
    editcap -t 14272376 capture2.pcap capture2-shifted.pcap     
    mergecap -w merged.pcap capture1-shifted.pcap capture2-shifted.pcap
```

Comment: the -t flag shift the time. it doesn't set the time. you have to compare the two captures to know how many seconds to shift

Answer (score 0):

mergecap from wireshark will merge the frames from two pcap files in chronological order based on the timestamps in the pcap files. See the [mergecap manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html) for more information.

Comment: No, even without the -a switch, it still appends the two files instead of interleave. `mergecap traffic1.pcap traffic2.pcap -w mtraffic.pcap`

Comment: There wouldn't be a `-a` flag if it always appended, so if it's not merging the files based on time stamp, there's a bug in mergecap.  Please file a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org), and attach the files you're trying to merge to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mergecap` command, which comes with Wireshark; it can merge multiple files based on the packet time stamps so that the merged file has all the packets, in time stamp order.